# How to correct the colors on a LED(WS2812/SMD5050) strip?

Tags: formula, rgb, lookup, led

I am using an LED strip of an cascade of 30 WS2812 RGB LEDs.

Since the intensity of each color channel is different I like to adjust the output. My idea is to have a formula that takes a std. RGB value and spits out the corrected one.

The [ws2812 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf) shows a table with intensity. I am looking for a way to get a formula to calculate the the GBR value from a RGB one.

There is a [adafruit LED lib](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) but I didn't figured out how they do the translation of the RGB values.

So how is the good way to figure out/get the right formula to perform a RGB to WS2812 RGB conversion?

Comment: You cannot. The data in the datasheet are not a full characterization of colours, in order to calculate the outputs. And I would not trust too much such data (either for manufacturing, and because with time LEDs, coating and phosphorus degrade). You should but a photospectrometer. 'Calibration softwares" (e.g. ArgyllCMS) can find the matrix you need to convert sRGB numbers into hardware values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [FastLED](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) library, then there's built-in functionality to perform color-correction.

See [`LEDColorCorrection`](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/08388047ac3e0ebcaafe71563ae2a55421d70c02/src/color.h#L9-L32) in file `color.h`.

See an example of how to use FastLED to do [ColorCorrection](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/examples/ColorTemperature/ColorTemperature.ino).

I would recommend just trying the predefined values (or make up your own ... it's just an `RGB` value).  If you're using typical consumer strips, note that strips vary ... between vendors, between manufacturing runs, based on temperature, etc.  Perception also `[varies][4]` based on surrounding environment.

Comment: thx for sharing. I am more interested into the formula/model that gives the correction values

Comment: I don't see anything fancy .. it appears to simply be a linear scaling on a per-color basis.  e.g., if the green LEDs output 2x what you expect, you'd set the green byte to 0x80.

If you want to apply proper color correction, you'd first need to characterize the output of the LED (e.g., with expensive, calibrated color sensors) under the conditions you'd be using them ... and at their various output levels.

*** FastLED just lets you estimate the adjustment, such as based on an average output difference between the colors....